# How to search for a string containing dot in a file?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, findstr

I have text file contains text someting like this,now I wanted to find the string which consist of `iris_cms.*`

for example sed,grep or findstar to search for a string from a below script and put it in a text file

Expected Output:

```
iris_cms.tblremaininglimit
iris_cms.tblproductionlog
iris_cms."PKGTRANSACTION"
iris_cms"UIPKGPRSCUSTOMER"
iris_cms."UIPKGPRSRELATIONSHIP"
iris_cms.getrelationshipidpan
iris_cms.getrelationshipid
```

for the input file contents:

```
ALTER TABLE iris_cms.tblremaininglimit MODIFY (is_ind_limit DEFAULT 0,ind_amount_id DEFAULT 0);

ALTER TABLE iris_cms.tblproductionlog MODIFY (export_status DEFAULT 0,logdatetime DEFAULT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS'));

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE iris_cms."PKGTRANSACTION"

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE iris_cms."UIPKGPRSCUSTOMER"

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE iris_cms."UIPKGPRSRELATIONSHIP" AS

ALTER FUNCTION iris_cms.getrelationshipidpan COMPILE;

ALTER FUNCTION iris_cms.getrelationshipid COMPILE;
```

Comment: Input is absent and output is not clear.

Comment: @Corentin Limier I wanted to search string which contains iris_cms.* till first space

Comment: Please edit your question with an input and the exact expected output.

Comment: Show us your effort(s) to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` will be the easiest

```
$ grep -o 'iris_cms\.[^[:space:]]*' file

iris_cms.tblremaininglimit
iris_cms.tblproductionlog
iris_cms."PKGTRANSACTION"
iris_cms."UIPKGPRSCUSTOMER"
iris_cms."UIPKGPRSRELATIONSHIP"
iris_cms.getrelationshipidpan
iris_cms.getrelationshipid
```

you need to escape literal dot, since it has a special meaning.

Comment: can we do this with findstr on windows machine?

Comment: sorry, not sure what that program is. If it has regex support it should be able to get the match and if also supports extract `-o` only the matched part, instead of the whole line.